# Insert a text value automatically in cell B1 of an excel sheet if A1from another excel sheet

Tags: excel

Good Day,
I have 02 excel sheets, one has all the database entry (single column) and in 2nd i've created a DD list and made a link to the database sheet from first excel file. The second excel file' sheet has 2 columns, one contains DD list (working nice) and 2nd column is part number in reference to first column (for e.g first column Duct Temp sensor and 2nd column has its relevant part#) now for this part # column also i have created DD list. but what i want is to automatically generate part# if i select duct temp sensor from DD list. I have about 90 entries and dont want to select part# each time. I want that once i select appropriate TAG (description) thru DD list in first column the 2nd column automatically compares the text and insert part# in the cell.
Regards

Comment: please take a look the link before asking question http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

1. What is "DD" ?  i use excel for 20 years and never heard this expression
2. it's nearly impossible to read your post;

   - Please add double-new line  (press ENTER 2 times) every time you finish to write an idea.
   - set items or steps in bullets or numbers
3. to answer the question in the title:

excel formula in one cell doesn't have ways to set value in another cell.  that's not how excel works. Otherwise you have to use macros*

if you want to have a cell changed  in B1 by the value in A1, you should write the appropriate  formula in B1.

the way to refer a formula in another worksheet is sheetName!A1

or for ranges:   sheetName!A1:C3

---

- actually there's an ugly way, but it doesn't solve your problem, and it's way too ugly to be useful